# Force a prettified URL with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

So have rewritten my ugly php URL to something prettier:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^main/photo([^/\.]+)/?.html$ main/details.php?gid=$2pid=$1
```

However, now I want to force anyone who goes to

```
http://www.example.com/main/details.php?gid=20&pid=5
```

to redirect to

```
htto://www.example.com/main/photo5.html
```

I have tried the following RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/main/details\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^main/details.php?gid=(.*)&pid=(.*) http://www.example.com/main/photo$1.html [R=301,L]
```

But that didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look into the [request line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1) to determine if the current request URI is the original. Additionally you need to use the `RewriteCond` directive to test the query of the URI:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /main/details\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([^&]*&)*)pid=([0-9]+)(&.*)?$
RewriteRule ^main/details\.php$ /main/photo%3.html? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I get send to photo.html?pid=5.

Comment: Now I'm redirected to photogid=73&.html. Which part determines what is captured by %1?

Comment: EDIT: Found it, you will need to change %1 to %3.